# Telegram-bot is restarting infinitely on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, telegram-bot

My telegram-bot well works locally - start only once, and I have sucсess when I deploys it on heroku. But if I run it on heroku, my bot infintely restart. What is a problem? This my logs:

```
2022-05-15T18:35:32.974856+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:32.974777 #4]  INFO -- : Bot has been started
2022-05-15T18:35:32.974863+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:32.974841 #4]  INFO -- : Starting bot
2022-05-15T18:35:33.244307+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:33.244226 #4]  INFO -- : Bot has been started
2022-05-15T18:35:33.244322+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:33.244288 #4]  INFO -- : Starting bot
2022-05-15T18:35:33.499636+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:33.499572 #4]  INFO -- : Bot has been started
2022-05-15T18:35:33.499647+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:33.499628 #4]  INFO -- : Starting bot
2022-05-15T18:35:33.800255+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:33.800185 #4]  INFO -- : Bot has been started
2022-05-15T18:35:33.800265+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:33.800246 #4]  INFO -- : Starting bot
2022-05-15T18:35:34.054451+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:34.054384 #4]  INFO -- : Bot has been started
2022-05-15T18:35:34.054461+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:34.054444 #4]  INFO -- : Starting bot
2022-05-15T18:35:34.314412+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:34.314347 #4]  INFO -- : Bot has been started
2022-05-15T18:35:34.314422+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:34.314405 #4]  INFO -- : Starting bot
2022-05-15T18:35:34.573674+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:34.573610 #4]  INFO -- : Bot has been started
2022-05-15T18:35:34.573683+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:34.573667 #4]  INFO -- : Starting bot
2022-05-15T18:35:34.832570+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:34.832504 #4]  INFO -- : Bot has been started
2022-05-15T18:35:34.832580+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:34.832564 #4]  INFO -- : Starting bot
2022-05-15T18:35:35.095775+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:35.095692 #4]  INFO -- : Bot has been started
2022-05-15T18:35:35.095787+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:35.095767 #4]  INFO -- : Starting bot
2022-05-15T18:35:35.341539+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:35.341454 #4]  INFO -- : Bot has been started
2022-05-15T18:35:35.341546+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:35.341525 #4]  INFO -- : Starting bot
2022-05-15T18:35:35.607636+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2022-05-15T18:35:35.607563 #4]  INFO -- : Bot has been started
```

There is my Procfile:

```
web: ruby my_app.rb -p $PORT
worker: ruby telegram-bot/poll.rb
```

There is myapp.rb. It is link on my bot, when I start my app on Heroku:

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  redirect 'https://t.me/pyskor_poll_bot', 303
end
```

There is poll.rb(my bot code):

```
# coding: utf-8
#require '/home/oleksiy/documents/pyskor_poll_bot/config/environment'
require 'dotenv'
#token = Dotenv.load('bot_token.env')
token = Dotenv.load(File.expand_path('../telegram-bot/bot_token.env', __dir__))
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)
require 'telegram/bot'
require 'json'

require File.expand_path('../bot_files/fill_tables', __dir__)
require File.expand_path('../bot_files/menu', __dir__)
require File.expand_path('../bot_files/results', __dir__)
require File.expand_path('../bot_files/confirm_poll_again', __dir__)
require File.expand_path('../bot_files/first_question', __dir__)
require File.expand_path('../bot_files/all_next_questions', __dir__)
require File.expand_path('../bot_files/checking_message', __dir__)
require File.expand_path('../bot_files/finish_polling', __dir__)
require File.expand_path('../bot_files/update_users_table', __dir__)
require File.expand_path('../bot_files/telegram_channels', __dir__)

token = ENV['POLL_BOT_TOKEN']

questions_counter = 0
first_question = true
poll = false
points = 0
previously_genres_markup = nil
previously_categories_markup = nil
previously_chapters_markup = nil
prev_didnot_subscribed_markup = nil
previously_markup_genre_text = ""
previously_markup_category_text = ""
previously_markup_chapter_text = ""
previously_kb = nil
previously_message_id = 0
polling_name = ""
polling_passed = false
passed_polling_id = 0
confirm_back = false
check_message = false
genres_array = ["Історія України", "Футбол"]

test_file = File.open(File.expand_path('../json/questions.json', __dir__),"rb")
test_hash = JSON.parse(test_file.read)
questions_count = 0
questions = []
terrible_mark = ""
bad_mark = ""
medium_mark = ""
good_mark = ""
unique_mark = ""
test_file.close

fill_polling_table()
fill_telegram_channel_table()
#puts(ENV['RAILS_ENV'])
loop do
  begin
    Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token, logger: Logger.new($stderr)) do |bot|
      bot.logger.info('Bot has been started')
      #delete_kb = Telegram::Bot::Types::ReplyKeyboardRemove.new(remove_keyboard: true)
      #bot.api.send_message(reply_markup: delete_kb)
      bot.listen do |message|
        Thread.start(message) do |message|
          begin
            if message.class == Telegram::Bot::Types::Message and poll == true
              if message.text != "/stop"
                check_message, points = checking_message(bot, message, questions, check_message, points)
              end

              if questions_counter == questions_count-2 and message.text != "/stop"
                finish_polling(bot, message, test_hash, questions_count, polling_name, points)
                poll = false
                first_question = true
                questions_counter = 0
                #bot.api.send_photo(chat_id: message.chat.id, photo: Faraday::UploadIO.new('~/Desktop/jennifer.jpg', 'image/jpeg'))
                update_users_table(bot, message, polling_name, points)
                points = 0
              end

          elsif message.class == Telegram::Bot::Types::Message and poll == false
              #puts(message.chat.username)
              #puts(message.chat.id)
              #puts(message.class)
              if message.text == "/start"
                hello_message = "Привіт, #{message.from.first_name}!"
                bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: hello_message)
              elsif message.text == "/hellobot"
                bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "\u{1F600}")
                bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "\u{1F44B}")
              elsif message.text == "/menu"
                previously_genres_markup = menu(bot, message)
              elsif message.text == "/messages"

              else
                if message.chat.id.to_s[0] != '-'
                  bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "\u{26D4} Невірна команда!")
                end
              end
            end

            if message.class == Telegram::Bot::Types::CallbackQuery

              if genres_array.include?(message.data)
                previously_categories_markup = genres(bot, message)
                previously_markup_genre_text = message.data
              end

              if message.data == "Telegram-канали"
                previously_chapters_markup = telegram_channels(bot, message)
                previously_markup_category_text = message.data

              elsif message.data == "results"
                results(bot, message)
              end

              if message.data.include?("subscribed")
                channels = put_in_channels_tables(bot, message, previously_markup_genre_text)
                kb = []
                if message.data == "didn't subscribed"
                  channels.each do |channel|
                    kb.push(
                      [
                        Telegram::Bot::Types::InlineKeyboardButton.new(text: channel.name, callback_data: channel.channel_id)
                      ]
                    )
                  end
                  kb.push(
                    [
                      Telegram::Bot::Types::InlineKeyboardButton.new(text: 'Назад', callback_data: "back_to_chapters")
                    ]
                  )
                  prev_didnot_subscribed_markup = Telegram::Bot::Types::InlineKeyboardMarkup.new(inline_keyboard: kb)
                end
              end

              if message.data[0] == '@'
                channel_info(bot, message)
              end

              md_split = message.data.split('_')
              if md_split[0] == "back"
                if message.data == "back_to_genres"
                  bot.api.edit_message_text(chat_id: message.from.id, text: "Опитування", message_id: message.message.message_id, reply_markup: previously_genres_markup)
                  polling_passed = false
                  #restart = false

                elsif message.data == "back_to_categories"
                  bot.api.edit_message_text(chat_id: message.from.id, text: previously_markup_genre_text, message_id: message.message.message_id, reply_markup: previously_categories_markup)
                  polling_passed = false

                elsif message.data == "back_to_chapters"
                  bot.api.edit_message_text(chat_id: message.from.id, text: previously_markup_category_text, message_id: message.message.message_id, reply_markup: previously_chapters_markup)
                  polling_passed = false

                elsif message.data == "back_to_didnot_subscribed"
                  bot.api.edit_message_text(chat_id: message.from.id, text: "Канали, на які ви НЕ ПІДПИСАНІ", message_id: message.message.message_id, reply_markup: prev_didnot_subscribed_markup)
                  polling_passed = false
                end
              end

              md_split = message.data.split('_')
              if test_hash[0].keys.include?(md_split[0]) == true
                polling_name = md_split[0]
                #if polling_passed == true
                  #user = User.find_by(polling_id: passed_polling_id)
                  #user.destroy
                  #polling_passed = false
                #end

                if User.exists?(telegram_id: message.from.id) and md_split[1] != "restart"
                  polling_passed, passed_polling_id = confirm_poll_again(bot, message, polling_name, polling_passed, passed_polling_id)
                end

                if md_split[1] == "restart"
                  questions_count, questions = first_question(bot, message, test_hash, polling_name)
                  first_question = false
                  poll = true
                end

                #if polling_passed == false
                if polling_passed == false
                    questions_count, questions = first_question(bot, message, test_hash, polling_name)
                    first_question = false
                    poll = true
                  # See more: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup
                end
              end
            end

            if message.class == Telegram::Bot::Types::Message and first_question == false
              if message.text == "/stop"
                poll, first_question, questions_counter, points = stop(bot, message, polling_name, previously_genres_markup)
              else
                questions_counter += 1
                all_next_questions(bot, message, questions, questions_counter)
              end
            end
          #rescue
            #bot.logger.info('Error!!!')
          end
        end
      end
      bot.logger.info('Bot has been finished')
    end
  rescue
    puts("Loop do error")
  end
end
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: For starters, your `Procfile` is malformed. There should be colons after `web` and `worker`, e.g. `web: ruby my_app.rb -p $PORT`

Comment: I put this colons. I just added view of Procfile on Heroku in my question. On Heroku Procfile is displaying without colons. So, my Procfile havn't mistakes. I have already edited it there

Comment: Can you show you `my_app.rb`? Or at least a [mre]?

Comment: You can find my project on Git: https://github.com/PyskorOleksiy/pyskor_poll_bot. Look at Procfile for first time, because I did not made Readme.txt

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works. Questions here must be self-contained. We're not going to go off-site to dig through your code on GitHub. Please [edit] the relevant code directly into your question.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I have already edited my question. I found mistake -                                elsif message.text == "/messages". So, I have a question: is it reason of my problem on Heroku, that I forgot put task that started when message.text == "/messages" is true? Locally all work without any problems, even with that mistake